# Expectation of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

A geometrically distributed random variable has expectation $\frac{1}{p}$. This result is usually proved by what seems to me to be an unnecessarily clumsy and artificial, albeit not hard, calculation.

My question: Is this necessary? Is there really no qualitative „one-line“ argument that establishes this intuitive result rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which calculation you have in mind; I'm assuming the one based on manipulating the geometric series. Here is a more conceptual argument. A geometric random variable $X$ describes the number of times we need to flip a coin with $\mathbb{P}(H) = p$ until we see heads. After flipping one coin, either we get heads with probability $p$ which means we're done, or we get tails with probability $1 - p$ which means we need to wait $X$ more flips again, for a total of $X + 1$ flips. This gives

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = p + (1 - p)(\mathbb{E}(X) + 1)$$

and rearranging gives $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{p}$ as desired. This is more or less equivalent to a certain manipulation of the geometric series but now the meaning of that manipulation is clear (conditioning on the first flip) which is nice.

For an argument fully consistent with the intuitive idea we may need to analyze the sums $X_1 + \dots + X_n$ of iid copies of a geometric variable. These sums describe the indices of appearances of heads in a long sequence of coin flips which at least intuitively gives $X_1 + \dots + X_n \approx \frac{n}{p}$ and I think this can be justified by appealing to the law of large numbers (for a *Bernoulli* random variable, and then again for the geometric random variable to conclude $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{p}$ from this). This, I think, fully justifies the intuitive argument but it's also technically much harder than the simple computation above.

Comment: Thanks. I did think of the second argument, but thought ist was a bit of an overkill. The first one indeed does the trick and makes elegant use of the memoriless property, I wonder why it is not used in literature instead of the geometric series calculation (or maybe it is and I‘ve seen a wrong sample).

Comment: I've seen it around somewhere, maybe on math.SE; it's certainly not original to me in any way!